# Match user IP address with sql database entry in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Can't figure out what's wrong with this code, but it is not returning anything for $result:

```
    // check to see if user has already voted
  $current_user = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $select_query = "SELECT * FROM w_poll_counter WHERE user_IP = " . $current_user;
  echo $select_query;

  $result = mysql_query($select_query);
  echo $result;

  if($result)
  {
    //user already voted - show results page
    header("Location: show_results.php");
    exit();
  }
```

The echo statements are for debugging purposes and will be removed once I've (or you've!) solved this problem. echo $select_query is returning that variable how I expect it, but echo $result is returning nothing at all. I'm able to cast multiple votes from my same IP address during testing. This is undesirable!

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: 1) You need to quote the IP address  2) Stop using mysql_* functions. They're not safe, and they've been deprecated and removed as of PHP7. Switch your code to use PDO/mysqli, and take advantage of parameter binding so that you don't need to worry about quoting variables yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your advice on PDO/mysqli but I'm not sure you understood my issue. The $select_query is fine and includes the IP address properly when I view the echo statement. It is $result that is coming up empty. Maybe I didn't understand your answer...?

Comment: Strings need to be quoted. An IP address is considered a string, not a number.

Comment: Yeah now I got it. Thanks! Didn't understand your answer at first and thought I was quoting correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try quoting properly you query

```
 $select_query = "SELECT * FROM w_poll_counter WHERE user_IP = '" . $current_user ."';";
```

Comment: Thank you! As the 2nd person of 2 respondents to point out that I wasn't quoting properly (when I thought I was), I decided to look into it and now everything works. Can't thank you enough!

Comment: If my answer is right please mark it as accepted .. this is also a good way for thanking ..

Comment: Unfortunately, a new problem has now arisen.

Comment: I've cleared out the database and made it empty with no records, yet cannot vote. It seems the code is not checking the current user IP address against anything and is kicking me to the results page without allowing me to vote.

Comment: if you have a new problem  then post a new properly .,. question ..since you've already had the correct answer to the previous question.. and in the new question show all the info strickly related the these  question .

Comment: You should insert almost an ip in  your db for check ..or re sign in the user  ..

Comment: Thanks - I went and typed up an all new question as you recommended and then it got rejected because I'm only allowed to post once every 90 mins?!? There is no sign in for users right now, which is why I am trying to use the IP address for checking... Is the problem with my if($result) statement? If so, will the 'almost' you recommend fix that?